# Specifying an API version when executing anonymous Apex

Tags: apex, execute-anonymous

It appears that Anonymous Blocks always run at the API version of their respective executing Organization.

Is this configurable?

I don't see this [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_anonymous_block.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify a version by invoking it via [Tooling REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_resources.htm)

`/services/data/vXX.X/tooling/executeAnonymous/?anonymousBody=...`

Comment: Right. It is simply a REST call.